# How to scale down Image with DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I have `DoubleAnimations`'s to move my `Image` element from one place to another, however when I've tried adding in another `DoubleAnimation` to scale the image down, my code breaks, this is my code:

```
private Point GetAbsolutePosition(UIElement element)
{
   var ttv = element.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
   return ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
}

private void MoveToSolarSystem_Start()
{
        var imageToMoveToPoint= GetAbsolutePosition(imageToMoveTo);
        var myImagePoint= GetAbsolutePosition(myImage);
        var offsetX = imageToMoveToPoint.X - myImagePoint.X;
        var offsetY = imageToMoveToPoint.Y - myImagePoint.Y;

        var translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        myImage.RenderTransform = translateTransform;

        ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        myImage.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;

        var scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 100,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };

        var animationX = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = offsetX + 50,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };

        var animationY = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = offsetY + 50,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };



        Storyboard.SetTarget(animationX, translateTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationX, "X");


        Storyboard.SetTarget(animationY, translateTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationY, "Y");

        Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, scaleTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, "X");


        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        storyboard.Children.Add(animationX);
        storyboard.Children.Add(animationY);
        storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();

}
```

I receive this error when I debug `Cannot resolve TargetProperty X on specified object.'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to set: 
`Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");` 
instead `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, "X");`

Comment: @marcinax Doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign only one `RenderTransform` to a control. Fortunately, the [`CompositeTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositetransform(v=vs.95).aspx) allows you to apply multiple effects at once.

There's two things to change in your code. First, replace the code where you create the transforms, to create only the `CompositeTransform`:

```
var compositeTransform = new CompositeTransform();
myImage.RenderTransform = compositeTransform;
```

(replace subsequent references of `translateTransform` and `scaleTransform` by `compositeTransform`)

The second thing is that the properties names are different on `CompositeTransform`. So you need to adapt your animations:

```
 Storyboard.SetTarget(animationX, compositeTransform);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationX, "TranslateX");

 Storyboard.SetTarget(animationY, compositeTransform);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationY, "TranslateY");

 Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation, compositeTransform);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation, "ScaleX");
```